# jQuery form alignment plugin?

Tags: jquery, css, forms

I found the following jQuery form alignment plugin in the comment of a blog post:

```
jQuery.fn.autoWidth = function(options) 
{ 
  var settings = { 
        limitWidth   : false 
  } 

  if(options) { 
        jQuery.extend(settings, options); 
    }; 

    var maxWidth = 0; 

  this.each(function(){ 
        if ($(this).width() > maxWidth){ 
          if(settings.limitWidth && maxWidth >= settings.limitWidth) { 
            maxWidth = settings.limitWidth; 
          } else { 
            maxWidth = $(this).width(); 
          } 
        } 
  });   

  this.width(maxWidth); 
}
```

I included that as `form_autoWidth.js` in my form page.

I also called this plugin from a separate file, `form_align.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.cleartext').autoWidth();
});
```

Shouldn't this align the `.cleartext` input fields?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the file in which you call the function to autowidth the input fields is after the jquery external file.